# Concrete example of a two-dimensional harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I am a student of mathematics and some time ago I showed in general that for a two-dimensional harmonic oscillator one can apply the recurrence theorem. So far so good.. now I would like to have a concrete example of a two-dimensional harmonic oscillator. Can you giuve me one?

Comment: What about a pendulum?

Comment: What kind of pendulum?

Comment: A ball attached to a string.

Comment: Sorry but could you be a little more concrete? I think there have to be certain circumstances and so on.

Comment: The ball should not be displayed much from equilibrium in order for the small-angle-approximation to be valid. Otherwise you'll get quartic anharmonicities.

Comment: Vertical mass-spring system?? i.e. a mass on the end of a spring hanging vertically and displaced from equilibrium

Comment: Do you understand that a pendulum moving in a plane is an harmonic oscillator? Then let it move in 3 dimensions. Some additional constraints would be: no drag, mass of the ball highly concentrated, mass of the string negligible, no bending of the string, no spin of the ball, .... But the best thing is to do the experiment and see how good the approximation is.

Comment: What exactly is a two-dim pendulum, is that the spherical pendulum? And this is an harmonic oscillator when assuming no friction and small amplitudes?

Answer (score 3):

The harmonic oscillator is so incredibly important in physics as a whole because of the following consideration. For a more or less smooth potential $V(x)$ with a local minimum at position $x_0$, one can taylor-expand around that minimum:
$$V(x)\approx V(x_0)+\frac{V''(x_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2+\mathcal{O}((x-x_0)^3).$$
The linear term is zero, otherwise it wouldn't be a minimum. Also, the coefficient in front of the quadratic term has to be positive for the same reason. Often, potentials are symmetric around local minima due to the symmetry of the problem, in which case all the odd-power terms will vanish as a rule, so the approximation is even better. The pendulum mentioned in the comments is an example for this. There, the potential has a cosine dependence on the displacement.

Due to energy considerations it is immediately clear that the region of applicability of the *harmonic approximation* (that's what it's called by the way) will not be left. Therefore, it is safe to replace the full potential by the quadratic ("harmonic") approximation.

For the desired two-dimensional harmonic oscillator, the argument is exactly the same. If it is supposed to be isotropic, meaning that the restoring force's magnitude only depends on the distance from the equilibrium point, not on the direction, the potential is rotationally symmetric around it's minimum (at least up to second order).

*Exact* harmonic oscillators are quite rare in physics. They're almost always approximations following the above scheme.

Comment: Okay, then as an example of a two-dimesnional harmonic oscillator I can f.e. take a pendulum (a mass hanging on a bar) with small amplitudes. Then what does the recurrence theorem say? That the flow generated by the divergence free vectorfield returns in the neighboorhoud of this condition infinetly often. How does this work, is friction neglected?